# How to solve $\int_0^{-2w}\phi^{-k-\frac{1}{2}}\frac{{_2F_1(k-\frac{1}{2},k,k+\frac{1}{2};1-\frac{k-\frac{3}{2}}{\phi})}}{\sqrt{-\phi-2\omega}}$?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, special-functions

Please help me to solve the integral:

$$\int_0^{-2w}\phi^{-k-\frac{1}{2}}\frac{{_2F_1(k-\frac{1}{2},k,k+\frac{1}{2};1-\frac{k-\frac{3}{2}}{\phi})}}{\sqrt{-\phi-2\omega}}$$

I have solved this in Mathematica. But I am not able to way a 
general result even in the table of integrals.

Comment: Do you mean for the upper limit of integration to be $-\omega$?

Comment: yes , the limits are from 0 to −ω